# box-sizing: border-box not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately, the inner div won't get a width of 100% of the parent less parents padding.

I found different solutions on the internet like adding `inherit` to the inner container. But that's not working either.
What am I missing?

The green container should positioned absolute to overlapping the parent's top border.

https://jsfiddle.net/3my8p964/

Thank you.

Comment: left:0;right:0; instead of width:100%

Comment: remove position: absolute. You're removing the inner element from the flow

Comment: You have added absolute position to inner class. removing that will work.

Comment: But this should be an absolute positioned container since it's overlapping the parent's top border.